# 404 Message when doing create operation in Node Js

Tags: html, node.js, post

This is the page with the table on it

> 

```
import { React, useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import { useNavigate } from 'react-router-dom';

import CourseList from '../components/CourseList';

function CoursesPage({ setCourse }) {
    // Use the Navigate for redirection
    const redirect = useNavigate();

    // Use state to bring in the data
    const [courses, setCourses] = useState([]);

    // RETRIEVE the entire list of Courses
    const loadCourses = async () => {
        const response = await fetch('/MongoCourses');
        const courses = await response.json();
        setCourses(courses);
    } 
    

    // UPDATE a single Course
    const onEditCourses = async course => {
        setCourse(course);
        redirect("/update");
    }


    // DELETE a single Courses  
    const onDeleteCourse = async _id => {
        const response = await fetch(`/MongoCourses/${_id}`, { method: 'DELETE' });
        if (response.status === 204) {
            const getResponse = await fetch('/MongoCourses');
            const courses = await getResponse.json();
            setCourses(courses);
        } else {
            console.error(`Unable to delete course. Error message = ${_id}, status code = ${response.status}`)
        }
    }

    // LOAD all the Courses
    useEffect(() => {
        loadCourses();
    }, []);

    // DISPLAY the Courses
    return (
        <>
            <h2>List of Courses</h2>
            <p>This is an ongoing list of courses I've taken for my Computer Science Degree.</p>
            <CourseList 
                courses={courses}
                onEdit={onEditCourses} 
                onDelete={onDeleteCourse} 
            />
        </>
    );
}

export default CoursesPage;
```

This is the add table page

import React, { useState } from 'react';
import { useNavigate } from "react-router-dom";

// Change the icons, function names, and parameters
// to fit your portfolio topic and schema.

export const AddCoursePageForm = () => {

```
const [courseNumber, setNumber]     = useState('');
const [courseName, setName]         = useState('');
const [description, setDescription] = useState('');
const [courseDate, setDate]         = useState('');;


const redirect = useNavigate();

const addCourse = async () => {
    const newCourse = {courseNumber, courseName, description, courseDate };
    const response = await fetch('/MongoCourses', {
        method: 'post',
        body: JSON.stringify(newCourse),
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        },
    });
    if(response.status === 201){
        alert(`Successfully added ${courseName}`);
        redirect("/coursesPage");
    } else {
        alert(`Unable to add course. Please check all fields are filled out correctly. Error message =  ${response.status}`);
        redirect("/coursesPage");
    }
};


return (
    <>
    <article>
        <h2>Add a Course</h2>
        <p>Paragraph about this page.</p>
        <form onSubmit={(e) => { e.preventDefault();}}>
            <fieldset>
                <legend>What course are you adding?</legend>
                <label for="courseNumber">Course Number</label>
                <input
                    type="text"
                    placeholder="CS 101"
                    value={courseNumber}
                    onChange={e => setNumber(e.target.value)} 
                    id="courseNumber" 
                    required/>
                
                <label for="courseName">Course Name</label>
                <input
                    type="text"
                    value={courseName}
                    placeholder="Intro to Computer Science"
                    onChange={e => setName(e.target.value)} 
                    id="courseName" 
                    required/>

                <label for="description">Course Description</label>
                <textarea 
                    type="text"
                    placeholder="Course Description (500 characters or less)"
                    value={description}
                    onChange={e => setDescription(e.target.value)} 
                    id="description" 
                    maxlength="500" 
                    ></textarea>

                <label for="courseDate">Date Completed</label>
                <input
                    type="date"
                    placeholder="Date Completed"
                    value={courseDate}
                    onChange={e => setDate(e.target.value)} 
                    id="courseDate" />                
                    

                <label for="submit">
                <button
                    type="submit"
                    onClick={addCourse}
                    id="submit"
                >Add</button></label>
            </fieldset>
            </form>
        </article>
    </>
);
```

}

export default AddCoursePageForm;

I had this working a few weeks ago and I am lost on where I messed up.

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify the host in the "fetch" function. Assuming your React app is running on localhost:3000, when you make a fetch request like this, it attempts to call localhost:3000/MongoCourses, which is an invalid URL. This is why it returns a 404 error code.

```
const response = await fetch('http://<backend_url>/MongoCourses');
```